# the_silver_searcher: Don't search in files that have the filename X.

Tags: search

I'm using `ag` (https://github.com/ggreer/the_silver_searcher/blob/master/doc/ag.1.md) to search for a pattern in a directory.

What I'd like to do is:

```
ag SearchPattern --excludeFilesThatHaveThisIntheFileName *Test
```

is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

The option you are looking for is `--ignore`. From the man page:

> ```
>   --ignore PATTERN:
>        Ignore files/directories matching this pattern.
>        Literal file and directory names are also allowed.
> ```

After testing it, it seems the pattern must be a file glob instead of a regular expression.
Your line would then become:

> ag SearchPattern --ignore *Test